# How can I add a logo to a ggplot visualisation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, imagemagick, png, graphical-logo

I'm currently working on a ggplot column chart and I'm trying to add a logo to the bottom right. This is the code to the chart:

```
df <- data.frame(Names = c("2001", "2004", "2008", "2012", "2018"),
                  Value = c(47053, 68117, 171535, 241214, 234365))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Names, y = Value)) + 
              geom_col(fill = "#DB4D43") + theme_classic() +
              geom_text(aes(label =  Value, y = Value + 0.05), 
                        position = position_dodge(0.9), 
                        vjust = 0)
```

I followed this tutorial I found online, but for some reason, it won't let me adjust the size of the logo and it ends up looking too small no matter what I type on the image_scale function.

```
img <- image_read("Logo.png")
img <- image_scale(img,"200")
img <- image_scale(img, "x200")
g <- rasterGrob(img)

size = unit(4, "cm")

heights = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - size,size)
widths = unit.c(unit(1, "npc") - size, size)
lo = grid.layout(2, 2, widths = widths, heights = heights)

grid.show.layout(lo)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = lo))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=1:1, layout.pos.col = 1:2))
print(p, newpage=FALSE)
popViewport()

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row=2:2, layout.pos.col = 2:2))
print(grid.draw(g), newpage=FALSE)
popViewport()

g = grid.grab()

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)

rm(list=ls())
```

I found another tutorial and, after trying this, it doesn't show anything at all when I run it.

```
mypng <- readPNG('Logo.png')
print(mypng)

logocomp <- p + annotation_raster(mypng, ymin = 4.5,ymax= 5,xmin = 30,xmax = 35)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. A good suggestion would be to add the link for the tutorials you were trying to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `cowplot` package to easily add an image to any plot made with `ggplot`. I used the R logo as the image that needs to be added to the plot (using `magick` package to read it). One advantage of using `cowplot` is that you can easily specify the size and position of both the plot and the image.

```
library(cowplot)
library(magick)

img <- image_read("Logo.png")

# Set the canvas where you are going to draw the plot and the image
ggdraw() +
  # Draw the plot in the canvas setting the x and y positions, which go from 0,0
  # (lower left corner) to 1,1 (upper right corner) and set the width and height of
  # the plot. It's advisable that x + width = 1 and y + height = 1, to avoid clipping 
  # the plot
  draw_plot(p,x = 0, y = 0.15, width = 1, height = 0.85) +
  # Draw image in the canvas using the same concept as for the plot. Might need to 
  # play with the x, y, width and height values to obtain the desired result
  draw_image(img,x = 0.85, y = 0.02, width = 0.15, height = 0.15)
```

[image: Plot with image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grid.raster`, something like:

```
grid::grid.raster(img, x = 0.15, y = 0.05, width = unit(0.5, 'inches'))
```

`x` and `y` to define location of the image.
Adjust the number in `unit()` to resize the plot.