# How to add a logo to a ggplot image

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataframe that I've used to create a chart in `ggplot2`. Is there a simple way to add my logo (`img`) to the bottom right hand corner of the plot?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magick)

img <- image_read("https://i.ibb.co/k0rYhnr/logo.png") %>% 
  image_resize(300)

data <- 
  structure(list(Date = structure(c(18262, 18628, 18993), class = "Date"), 
                 Value = c(2, 3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"))

data %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(Date, Value)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: Suggested duplicates: [How can I add a logo to a ggplot2 visualization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442933/how-can-i-add-a-logo-to-a-ggplot-visualisation), [How to add logo to ggplot2 footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574732/how-to-add-logo-on-ggplot2-footer), [How to add logo to ggplot footer using +](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58883225/903061)